# Identity element in the K-group

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, k-theory

This is a question from page 552 of Atiyah and Singer's paper "The index of elliptic operators III". The line is "We suppose first that $X$ is compact so that $K(X)$ has an identity element."

Even if $X$ is noncompact, doesn't $K(X)$ always have an identity element, coming from the trivial line bundle?

Here I am understanding $K(X)$ to denote the group arising as a quotient of the free group generated by equivalence classes of complex vector bundles over $X$. I am understanding the ring structure to arise from tensor product. I don't see how compactness of $X$ is relevant.

Comment: If $X$ is noncompact, then the Grothendieck group of vector bundles does not define a cohomology theory. Generally one assume that $X$ is locally compact and *defines* $K(X)$ to be the kernel of $K(X_\infty)\rightarrow K(\ast)$, where $X_\infty$ is the one-point compactification of $X$ and the homomorphism is induced by the inclusion $\ast\hookrightarrow X_\infty$. Notice that the trivial bundle is not an element of the kernel.

Comment: Another way to describe what @Tyrone is saying is that we are dealing with compactly supported virtual vector bundles (though without seeing the context there is no reason to apriori assume this). A compactly supported virtual vector bundle is a pair of vector bundles which are isomorphic outside of a compact set. Necessarily they have virtual dimension 0 outside of a compact set. So the trivial line bundle is not in this if our space is not compact.

Comment: Thank you... I should have checked for definitions in "The index of elliptic operators I"

Comment: @QuartoBendir You should answer your own question and accept it. This pushs the question from the unanswered queue.